# Associativity of mixed matrix product and tensor product?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\bf A$ be an $l \times m$ matrix, $\bf B$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, and $\bf x$ be a row vector of any size. Will equality $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{B}\otimes \mathbf{x})=\mathbf{AB}\otimes\mathbf{x}$ always hold? Suppose $\bf x$ is of size $s$, then both sides get a matrix of size $l\times ns$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may verify the equality directly:
\begin{aligned}
A(B\otimes x)
&=A\pmatrix{B_{\ast1}x&\cdots&B_{\ast n}x}\\
&=\pmatrix{AB_{\ast1}x&\cdots&AB_{\ast n}x}\\
&=\pmatrix{(AB)_{\ast1}x&\cdots&(AB)_{\ast n}x}\\
&=(AB)\otimes x.
\end{aligned}